# Vector Differentiation for SVM

Tags: calculus

I am trying to deduce the basic mathematical formulas of [SVMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support-vector_machine) by playing around with different concepts. For using [SGD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent) I would like to know the derivation of the distance of the data points X from the SVMs hyperplane.

$$ w \in \mathbb{R}^n, b \in \mathbb{R}, X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m} $$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial w}\frac{w^TX+b}{||w||_2} = \frac{X||w||_2 - 2w(w^TX+b)}{||w||_2^2}$$

I am having doubts that this is correct since my numerical gradient approach is giving me different results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$||w||_2 = \displaystyle\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i^2}$, so its derivative wrt $w$ isn't $2w$ in the quotient rule.